# When scheduling spring batch using quartz or simple spring scheduling , its not starting from beginning

Tags: spring-batch, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have a simple chunk based spring batch job which i scheduled using quartz but the problem is I have one print statement in reader which is getting printed only at first ran. I am new to this so I want to understand , in scheduled batch job is reading happens only once??
My requirement is each run should read data from source. Can someone help how reader work in scheduled environment .  If any more information is require plz let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-a-job-instance-already-exists-and-is-complete-for-parameters/

Comment: Its not duplicate

Comment: Are you getting a new `JobInstance` with each run?  Are you passing unique parameters with each run to ensure that?